# estimate population size from samples

Tags: statistics

I don't think there is enough data to solve for this but wanted to run it by some folks smarter than me...

So given the data below where classes are a sample of a professor's entire career, can you determine the total number of classes taught?

Class 1: 10, 9, 1, 15, 13, 8, 1, 0, 5, 6, 3, 2, 0

Class 2: 1, 11, 11, 11, 4, 2, 3, 15

Class N: 1, 0, 3, 5, 7, 2, 0, 2, 9, 1

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant. To estimate a population size you need some sort of capture/recapture approach. You intuition is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much, Bey. This was literally driving me mad. Very much appreciate the support.